# Protractor Angular 4 E2E tests Async

Tags: angular, protractor

I can't run E2E tests of an Angular 4 app without turning of Synchronization or telling it the app is not an Angular App

```
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

when I don't do the above I get the following error:

```
- Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
```

I have been running tests succesfully with either of the two commands, but I am getting more and more timeouts because I have to use waits and expected conditions to be able to get the page to load.

Comment: Its possible that the angular app is using timeouts. Protractor does not support this, but it will support intervals, which can accomplish the same thing. Check out [this issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/169) on the repo for more info

Comment: try adding this to your config: `exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000000, jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000000 }}`

Answer (score 0):

The solution above is the only way I got my code to work, I haven't had any issues.
As far as I understand AngularJS and Angular 4's async isn't the same and protractor was built for AngulaJS

If I need to do a pause to wait for something to load I use:

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
      browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(foo), 5000, 'error: cant find foo');
```